# Return original contextmenu for textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea, contextmenu

I have got a div contains a textarea.

```
<div class="parent" style="width: 500px;height: 500px;">
   <textarea style="width: 100%;height:50%" class="children"></textaarea>
</div>
<script>
   $('.parent').bind('contextmenu',function(){
        showParentContextMenu();
   });
</srcipt>
```

When i right click on the textarea the contextmenu of its parent appear.So how to set original contextmenu(of browser) for textarea in this case!Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('.parent').children().bind('contextmenu', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
   });​
```

Comment: For the record: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.